# Using GeometricShapeFactory to create circle with radius in miles

Tags: java, jts-topology-suite

I'm new in PostgreSQL/PostGIS and I have a problem and don't know how to solve it.
I'm using GeometricShapeFactory.createCircle() method in Java to get Polygon from central point (lat/long) and radius, which is in miles. As I understood, setSize() method expects radius as extent. So, how to convert it to miles? I suppose that is the reason why I got the huge circle on map.
Also, I'm using hibernate spatial in my project.

This is my piece of code, but it doesn't display correctly polygon:

```
private Polygon getPolygonFromCircle(Double radius, Double latitude, Double longitude) {
    GeometricShapeFactory shapeFactory = new GeometricShapeFactory();
    shapeFactory.setCentre(new Coordinate(latitude, longitude));
    shapeFactory.setSize(radius * 2);
    shapeFactory.setNumPoints(32);

    Polygon circlePolygon = shapeFactory.createCircle();
    circlePolygon.setSRID(4326);

    return circlePolygon;
}
```

Comment: You're likely making a circle in *degrees* (which is of course useless). Look for documentation on how to work with geodetic circles.